# Dockerizing .NET Core app doesn't give the same output?

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I'm new in docker and I'm trying to dockerizing a .NET core app, the compiled app when I run it without a live server is should give this error.

[image]

the dockerfile I use to build an image for this app is

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env

WORKDIR /app
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o bin


WORKDIR /app/bin

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Rescue.Bridge.dll"]
```

the output when running the container is

[image]

my question is that I can't figure out what is missing/wrong so I can get the same output as the compiled version without docker?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to bind to a network address that doesn't exist in the docker container. You might consider binding to `0.0.0.0` to see if anything changes?

Comment: in the appsettings.json the IP settings is  "RescueBridge": {
      "IPAddress": "192.168.4.1",
      "Port": 6005
    },

are you proposing to change it to 0.0.0.0 and rebuild the image?

Comment: This is a listening port? Yes, change it to `0.0.0.0`, port `6005` and the listener will bind to all addresses in the container.

Comment: `192.168.4.155:0` seems to be incorrect

Answer (score 0):

When it comes container, you should not bind with specific `IP` address otherwise you should not able to access your application.

Add this in the Dockefile to listen on all interfaces.

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:6005
```

You will able to access the application from outside of the container.

Or you can update URL in the `appsettings.json`

```
  "App": {
    "APIURL": "http://0.0.0.0:6005/"
  },
```

Comment: I added this line to my docker file and rebuilt the image, the problem still exists

Comment: You need to expose the port eg "6005" outside your docker container and bind it to local machine port. Easiest way is to use Kitematic.exe and check what port is on container and bind it to local machine port in the settings tab of your container instance

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the compiled version not in the dockerized one, "`System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (49): Can't assign requested address 127.0.0.1:0`"

when I changed the connection setting, all worked well.